# eventListener works on variable which is supposed to be inside a function's private scope

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events

Here I have this input button element.A variable declared as `btn` is assigned a reference to that button using `document.getElementById('btn')`, but the `btn` variable is inside a function named `create`. As far I know functions create *private scope* which can't be accessed globally, but here I can manage to add `eventListener` to that variable without even invoking the function. How is this  possible?

```js
 function create(){
     var btn=document.getElementById('btn');
 }
 
 btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      alert('it worked !!');
 });
```

```html
<input type='button' value='button' id='btn'>
```

Comment: ids create implicit globals unfortunately.

Comment: i don't understand .can you please elaborate??

Comment: When you create an element with an id, the browser will create a variable with the same name. It is not your `btn` variable that is leaking, it is another `btn` variable declared in the global scope. Give your variable another name or change the id, you'll see it is not leaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an element with an id set, that id will be used as a key on the `window`-object which means it's globally available in a browser. See https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#named-access-on-the-window-object for more info.

In your case, if you don't name your inner variable btn, then you can't access it.

```js
 function create(){
     var innerBtn=document.getElementById('btn');
 }
 
 innerBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      alert('not going to happen !!');
 });
```

```html
<input type='button' value='button' id='btn'>
```

Also the other way around, even if you don't assign btn in the inner function, it would still be available to you to add your listener.

```js
 btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
      alert('it worked !!');
 });
```

```html
<input type='button' value='button' id='btn'>
```

Comment: if we can access element using just id name then why we have to use methods like document.getElementById() etc??

Comment: This is what the WHATWG spec says: `"Which IDs end up mapping to this API can vary over time, as new features are added to the Web platform, for example."` In other words, you can't be sure what is mapped and what is not. Names that already exists won't be mapped, and some bad code could easily just do `window.btn = document.getElementById('myotherelement');` or `window.btn = null;` and your code would break.